# mysql update with regexp

Tags: mysql, regex

I want to remove something from my table `1)` `32)` `121)` `1000)`... the format is `number` + `)`

I tried this code.

```
UPDATE articles SET 
title= REPLACE(title,'\d)', '' ) 
WHERE title regexp "\d)*"
```

Nothing happened in `phpmyadmin`, how to write correct?　Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't: Mysql doesn't support regex-based replace.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826) for a work-around.

Comment: so how to replace just `121)`? `UPDATE articles SET 
title= REPLACE(title,'121)', '' ) 
WHERE title regexp "121)*"` still not work, should i add-slashes to the `)`?

Comment: Just use `like`: `UPDATE articles SET title = REPLACE(title,'121)', '' ) WHERE title like '%121)%';`. Or just leave out the where clause - rows without `121)` won't be changed.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, I use  some php to solve this problem with a quickly method.

```
for ($i=1; $i<=9999; $i++){
 $my_regex = $i.')';
 mysql_query("UPDATE articles SET title = REPLACE(title,'".$i."', '' ) where title like '%".$i."%'");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have unique requirement where I need to replace inactive owner username. Where username contians *INACITVE* followed by village id. So I have used concat() funacion inside replace() function to replace dynamically.

```
 update Owner set username = replace(username, concat('_INACTIVE_',village_id) ,'') 
where village_id = 3363010;
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, depending on the size of the table, you could do a workaround with `substring` function.