# MySQL pattern matching and replace

Tags: mysql, pattern-matching

I have a table with settings column having the following data in three different rows:

```
{{product.description}}

{{user.email}}

{{last_date}}
```

I want to append the string '| format' with dynamic data, the output should be like this

```
{{product.description | format}}

{{user.email | format}}

{{last_date | format}}
```

I tried with MySQL [REPLACE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) method but problem is how to match this specified pattern.

What will be the UPDATE query for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use the REGEXP operator as follows:
SELECT (statement) REGEXP '{product.description}[.space.]|[.space.]format';
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What will be the UPDATE query to get the appropriate output

Comment: Please Check this link out. It has similar question and a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10465288/mysql-update-with-regexp